# How to Insert Password into SQL Server with Encrypted and Retrieve with Decrypted in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I am New to MVC, As I want to Insert Password with Encrypted into Database(Sql Server) when user Registered with his username and password, and when user want to login with his username and password, password should decrypt and Login.

This process should be happen, can any one help me is there  any way to solve this.
If anyone, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Implement any encryption-decryption logic in your stored procedure.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1363910.aspx?Store+passwords+in+encrypted+or+hash+in+database

Answer (score 0):

use membership provider, it eases in registeration and login and also it encryptes and decryptes passwords and check for username availability

[Check this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TsRsgiU5tA)

[Read this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)